# Formatting String for subprocess.run "No closing quotation"

Tags: python, subprocess, valueerror, shlex

I have this command to run:

```
'xcopy /e "%s" "%s"'%(executablesPath + "\\*", sourcePath+"\\Executables\\")
```

which is formatted to:

```
xcopy /e "I:\Storage$\tools\Executables\*" "C:\Win10x64-1903\Executables\"
```

and ran within:

```
subprocess.run(shlex.split(command))
```

What is causing the error `ValueError: No closing quotation`?

Comment: `"C:\Win10x64-1903\Executables\"` should be `"C:\Win10x64-1903\Executables"` (without the backslash in the end). Better yet: don't use an external command to copy files, use `shutil` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shlex.split` doesn't like the last backslash before the double quote. It seems like you want to escape this quote, hence the message.

quick fix: replace `sourcePath+"\\Executables\\"` by `os.path.join(sourcePath,"Executables")`

better fix: don't compose a command line just to split it again. Just use a list of arguments

```
subprocess.run(["xcopy","/e",os.path.join(executablesPath,"*"),os.path.join(sourcePath,"Executables")])
```

Better yet, use [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) to recursively copy a directory. No need for a non-portable external command. Something (untested) like:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(executablesPath,os.path.join(sourcePath,"Executables"))
```

Comment: While this is marked as the acceptable answer, it should be made aware that shutil.copy doesn't always make good for copying subdirectories and their contents. I have only been able to make good use of shutil.copy for individual files and using it within a recursive function for nested directories.

Comment: you're right. I've been slightly evasive about `shutil.copytree`. It has many limitations. Sometimes you have to create the dirs, sometimes not, ... there's some tuning to do but at least it's portable and doesn't depend on old xcopy